# git pull without any commit for merging while working on the same branch from two machines

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I work on a branch from office machine and home machine. I need to pull all the changes in by branch to current machine without any commit for merging.

For example: I worked from office for some days and pushed all the updates. Now on the very next day I need to work on the same from my home and I need all those changes in my home machine, for which I normally use `git pull`. The issue is that, when I use `git pull`, it will automatically create a commit with message like `Merge branch 'master' of bitbucket.org:username/project`. I don't need such a commit. This will be also pushed to the remote when I pushed my updates. I just need to update my project with the remote project. I hope there must be a solution.

What I do now is remove the project from local and clone it again.

Comment: Did you make any changes in your local (home) project before pulling the remote repository?

Comment: Nope. Did none because I know there are changes in remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `--no-commit` option in the [git docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html).

Comment: This one did the job!! :)